# How to change sms endpoint using with AWS SDK (Node.js)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-nodejs

Does anyone know how to change sms endpoint with ARN using aws sdk javascript? I am not sure if AWS Support this function but if anyone know about the way then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: change SMS endpoint how? Can you share details of what your expected results and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I wanna change the phone number with the subscription id. Is it possible? Should I remove the old subscription and create a new subscription with the new phone number?

Comment: @Smile_Man, unfortunately this is not possible

Comment: I see. So i delete the subscription and create the new susbcription with the new phone number! Thanks for your reply and care @syumaK